# Play FFMPEG while downloading

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

My internet connection is too slow for streaming videos. However, i found a way to download m3u8 files, which are used for streaming media, and I use ffmpeg to download and transcode the video via a very simple command:

```
ffmpeg -i file.m3u8 file.mp4
```

This does what i want, because it gives me a way to avoid the streaming which freezes too much. However, I would love to start watching what I want to watch before it's done downloading. Why am i not able to open the video file before it's finished? Since mp4 is a concat format. How can i make myself able to watch it while it's downloading?

Answer (score 3):

mp4 is NOT a concat format. To playback an MP4 a complete moov atom must exist, but the moov atom requires a list of ALL frames in the mdat.

Comment: Ok. This is helpfull thank you. What would be a good format?

Comment: what not transport stream?

Comment: Well. If i just copy the strean into mkv it wont play nicely in vlc if i forward

Comment: Well. Then I would not use an mkv. I would use a transport stream. I would also add `-acodec copy -vocdec copy` so the video is not transcoded also.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not only possible but even much simplier than you can imagine.

You can use this one-liner:

```sh
ffmpeg -i file.m3u8 -c:a copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -c:v copy -f ismv pipe:1 | tee file.mp4 | mpv -
```

#### What's going on there

###### FFMPEG part

1. We're downloading the required file. `file.m3u8` in this case. M3U8 files is usually an indexes of H264-encoded TS files. So I presume that this is mp4 container compatible segments with AAC audio. To save the time while downloading the file I have added `-c:a copy` and `-c:v copy` params. They mark audio and video streams as not-needed-to-be-reencoded.
2. We're adding `-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc` to fix audio streaming issues.
3. We're adding output format since we're outputting to stdout `-f ismv`. `ismv` is the same as `mp4` except the one little thing: it also adjusts `movflags` for streaming. See more info in the [ffmpeg formats documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#mov_002c-mp4_002c-ismv)
4. We're outputting everything to stdout using `pipe:1`

###### Tee part

1. Simply enough, we're just copying the stream incoming from FFMPEG both to output file and to stdout

###### MPV part

1. Simpliest part. We're just passing `-` as an input file to mark that we want to read incoming stdin stream

That's it. It just works)

Comment: This is a great solution! But I have two questions. (1) While I watch, is it possible to make FFMPEG download faster? When I don't pipe to MPV, it goes at 6x speed; instead, if I pipe it to MPV, it strangely goes at about 1x speed. Is it because each segment is downloaded only after being watched via MPV? (2) If, during the download, I try to open the file with another program, it has no audio. The same happens if I stop the download and I try to open it with MPV. Where is the audio track being stored during download?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .ts file format to play and save content simultaneously without need to wait for playing the video till the video gets completed

---

My story :
I also want to do same thing using ffmpeg or ffplay
I tried finding that can I play stream using ffplay and save it in file simultaneously but I can't find anything regarding it

so i tried saving content in .mp4 and playing it simultaneously but i got this error and I saw this error first time while playing mp4 and saving it simultaneously

by chance I got your question then I got to know about concat format

but I tried saving .ts file from .m3u8 stream few days ago, in that format I can easily save .ts stream using python and play using VLC simultaneously without any problem

By your question I got know about concat format
Thanks!

> please give me like,etc. what is available on this platform (which
> increases the reputations,etc.) so that i can answer and help friends
> like me and you without any post restrictions on my network.
>
> i am new to this platform so i don't know about it that much and due
> to use of NAT in our country my ip address has restrictions due to
> spam,etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).